# What is rails test command to exclude some test files or test name to be run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

What is rails test command to exclude some test files or test name to be run?

For example, I want to exclude 1 rb test file which is test/integration/trello_webhook_test.rb
I have try this commands:

```
rails test -t --ignore-testcase= "test/integration/trello_webhook_test.rb"
```

I give another try to exclude my test name contained "JSON" in trello_webhook_test.rb with this command:

```
rails test -t --ignore-name= "/JSON/"
```

But, both commands result in the test of trello_webhook_test.rb or the test name contained "/JSON/" was still run.
Thanks in advance for any response.

the rails test --help:
[rails test --help output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrvqK.png)

I'm using Windows 10 OS.

Best,
Randy

Comment: Have you tried `rails test --ignore-testcase= "test/integration/trello_webhook_test.rb"` e.g. without the `-t`? Also, can you verify that the file path is correct?

Comment: Yes I had. But, it return invalid argument: --ignore-testcase=
Test::Unit automatic runner.

Comment: trty with single quotes ' instead double " , and also try without space between = and quotes, like `rails test --ignore-testcase='test/integration/trello_webhook_test.rb'`

Comment: now the test is run. But, its still run trello_webhook_test.rb (it not exlcuded)

Answer (score 1):

According to help manual (`rails test --help`) you have to do:

```
rails test --exclude test/integration/trello_webhook_test.rb
```

Comment: No run for me. it return invalid option: --exclude
Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: bin/rails [options] [-- untouched arguments]

Comment: what you get with `rails test --help`?

Comment: just added the screen capture on the question

Comment: aaaaa you use Windows, can you edit and add this information in your question plz